# send multipart/form-data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In my Project I send Multipart form-data from angular side to nodejs. the format of data i received is

```
{ name: 'customer.test.14',
  email: 'test14@gmail.net',
  website: 'www.google.com',
  contact_name: 'Vijay',
  contact_number: '+123456789022',
  profile: 'Testing',
  provider_category: 'exchange',
  services_offered: 'Testing',
  description: 'Test',
  image:
   [ { size: 1474,
       type: 'image/png',
       path: 'bc31dac580a7c2086f306fe0b9b5182d/',
       basename: 'icon_dd_chart_grey.png' } ] }
```

I want to send data this to another api in nodejs. but api does not upload image.

here is my code

```
var request = require('request');
    var api_url = global.common.base_url + 'vcard/1.0.0/visit_card/' + req.param('uuid') +'/';
    console.log(req.body);
    request({
        url: api_url,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data;',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+req.cookies.apitoken
        },
        json: req.body,

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200 && !error){
            res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
        }else{          
            res.send(response.statusCode, { error: body });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Look into multer, https://github.com/expressjs/multer which is used for handling multipart/form-data in node js

Answer (score 2):

You can archive this using "**Okhttp3**". Please [refer this video tutorial form reference and usage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G89GtT1JMEc&t=170s) and [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/okhttp).

Eg: upload two bodies (json and a image) to a single endpoint at the same time:

```
const okhttp                = require('okhttp');

var MimeBuilder             = okhttp.MimeBuilder;
var Request                 = okhttp.Request;
var RequestBody             = okhttp.RequestBody;
var RequestBuilder          = okhttp.RequestBuilder;
var FormEncodingBuilder     = okhttp.FormEncodingBuilder;
var MultiPartBuilder        = okhttp.MultiPartBuilder;

let json    = JSON.stringify({title:'test'});
var image   = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test.jpg'));

let mp_body = new MultiPartBuilder().addPart(RequestBody.create(json, 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'))
                                    .addPart(RequestBody.create(image, new MimeBuilder().contentType('image/jpeg').contentTransferEncoding('binary').build()))
                                    .type(MultiPartBuilder.FORMDATA).build();

new RequestBuilder().url('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart')
                    .header('Authorization', 'Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN_HERE')
                    .POST(mp_body).buildAndExecute().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```